# Unable to update node entity fields using custom form

Tags: nodes, forms, taxonomy-terms, 9

There is a certain content type, in which there is a field to enter a node or taxonomy.
I want to create a new node for that content type using a custom form and register the node or taxonomy in the entity field.

```
$form['client_company'] = [
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
  '#tags' => TRUE,
  '#selection_settings' => array(
    'target_bundles' => array('vid', 'client'),
  ),
  '#weight' => '0',
];

$form['client_human'] = [
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type' => 'node',
  '#tags' => TRUE,
  '#selection_settings' => array(
    'target_bundles' => array('budle', 'client_human'),
  ),
  '#weight' => '0',
];
$form['url'] = [
  '#type' => 'url',
];


$node->field_project_refercompany->value = $form_state->getValue('client_company');        
$node->field_project_referclienthuman->value = $form_state->getValue('client_human');
$node->field_project_url->value = $form_state->getValue('url');
$node->save();
```

The $node, field_refercompany, field_project_referclienthuman, etc. are nodes and their field names, no error there.
However, even though I can create a new node, the above fields are blank and nothing is entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self Answer

```
$node->field_project_refercompany->target_id = $form_state->getValue('client_company')[0]['target_id'];
$node->field_project_referclienthuman->target_id = $form_state->getValue('client_human')[0]['target_id'];
$node->field_project_url->uri = Url::fromUri($form_state->getValue('url'))->toString();
```